# WPF White framework accessing custom property on custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, white-framework

Is there a way how to access custom property on custom control in WPF using White framework test ?

Let's say I have class like this:

```
public class MyButton : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {

    }

    public string MyCustomButtonProp { get { return "MyButtonInfo"; } }
}
```

Is there a way how to access MyCustomButtonProp via White framework in a test ? I read how custom controls are handled (https://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AdvancedTopics/CustomUIItems/) but that didn't lead me to conclusion how to access custom properties, only how to handle custom controls with nested controls. If I use standard White framework objects (Button in this case) I can interact with the button but that's not sufficient in my case.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Iam also interested in a solution 

Comment: Frankly, I gave up and we ended up with a paid solution from one of companies which offers automated WPF testing ...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write your own `AutomationPeer` to expose the property. Then you would need to extend the White control to expose your custom property.

Overriding the `AutomationPeer` is not that bad since you might be able to just inherit from another `AutomationPeer` to get 90% of the functionality you need.

Here is an example of how to write a [AutomationPeer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patrickdanino/2009/11/11/custom-controls-and-ui-automation/). Here is another [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/ui-automation-of-a-wpf-custom-control#customizations-in-a-derived-peer) I would take a look at which gives a much more broad overview of implementing the "server" side of UIA.

Comment: I have read the articles (Google cache: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_Ym2h2FveUMJ:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patrickdanino/2009/11/11/custom-controls-and-ui-automation/+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=in&client=firefox-b) but I could not solve my problem.  Maybe you could have a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500604/teststack-how-to-find-custom-controls-and-invoke-methods-fire-events?noredirect=1#comment93870793_53500604

Comment: @dominicjonas I will take a look at this soon because more than likely I will be attempting to add a custom field and pattern to a control at work soon.

Comment: @dominicjonas you may also find this interesting, a developer on teststack.white sent it to me a while ago and it helped me better understand the framework I was working in https://github.com/TestStack/uia-custom-pattern-managed/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It looks like that's exactly what I was looking for! 